# How do I add javascript to a login process without producing an error for using set_cookie and header?

Tags: javascript, php

This is from my login code

```
setcookie("userid", $user[id],time()+(60*60*24*5), "/", "");
setcookie("pass", $user[password],time()+(60*60*24*5), "/", "");
header('Location: /');
```

I would like to add some javascript so I can track the login with Mixpanel or Amplitude.

If I add it at the top of the code, it'll trigger an error for echoing content then setting headers (or cookies). If I add it at the bottom, it won't be seen as the redirect is before that.

Any ideas? Should I use query strings even thought that looks messy or a third cookie that deletes itself on a page view?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to echo your javascript with PHP?

Comment: I guess the javascript is going to call some API provided by Mixpanel or whoever? If so, just call the API from PHP instead. Much more reliable I'd have thought.

Comment: They don't have a php api. Only javascript. @ADyson

Comment: Can you edit the view? If so, send a variable to the template engine (by example: Smarty) and print your javascript on the template only if the value sent from PHP is true. `{if $logged == true}{literal}<script> put your JS code here </script>{literal}{/if}`

Comment: @desbest Mixpanel has a PHP library for their API: https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/php . And for amplitude there appear to be several 3rd-party libraries: https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=amplitude%20api%20php or you could write your own calls directly to their HTTP API. All that the Javascript you mentioned does is provide some ready-made client software that calls a HTTP API in the background. How else do you think the data gets from your app to the analytics server?

Comment: @JonathanParentLévesque I want the javascript to occur once when the user logs in, not on every page they view while logged in.

Comment: Put the script on the login page. You can also use `isset` to see if the value have been declared or not. `{if isset($afterLogging)}{literal}<script> put your JS code here </script>{literal}{/if}`

Comment: I've solved the problem now, and it involved setting two cookies.